# clickonce, customer specific update URL - How to manage

Tags: clickonce

I have a clickonce deployment issue/problem that I need help figuring out how to address. I have looked at the huge number of questions regarding clickonce already asked here, but without stumbling over a solution to my problem.

The situation is the following:

At work we are about to redevelop our application from a non .net based application to a .net based application, as a WPF application using clickonce for installation and update purposes. This is a management decision that can’t be changed, so suggestions that recommend otherwise will not help solve the issue.

We have at this point a 100+ customers/installations each with multiple users of our current application and a need for an easy way to control when updates are made available for each customer, and here the problem starts. It is my /our understanding of clickonce that the install and update URL’ are embedded in a signed manifest file, and I will therefore need a manifest file and a copy of the program files pr. Customer in order to control when each customer an update the system.

In my mind I would like a solution somewhat like this:

I create a site for the application/product e.g. myproductsite.com with a URL like myproductsite.com/application/install for initial install purposes without regard to the whom customer are and an URL like myproductsite.com/application/update/somecustomerid for update purposes. Each customer would have their own update folder/URL identified by somecustomerid to which update would be published whenever an update should be available for a particular customer. I would then make an admin tool that should ease the process of making the updates available in the customer specific folder/URL.

In order to accomplice this, the URL for updates would have to be specific for every customer due to the somecustomerid part of the URL, and it is my understanding that this can’t be taken from eg. The app.config file and merged into the URL when the program searched for updates. I hope there is someone out there that knows otherwise.

If I’m right, is there a way of making manifest files as a batch, so that the admin tool could make these manifest files and / or distribute them to the somecustomerid folder whenever an update should be available to one or more customers?

It is also my understanding that once an installation is made at a customer, it is very cumbersome, if not nearly impossible, to change the installation and update URL at my end, and still ensure clickonce will work.

I may have misunderstood the concept of clickonce completely, and therefor asking really silly questions, but I still have a need for updating some customers without updating others, and I still can’t figure out how to implement/manage the issue.

Other may have had similar issues. I can’t be the first one with a need for updating customers independently, so please share your experiences, Do’s and Don’ts.

Regards
Morten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickOnce by default assumes that *all* customers will install the application from the same location and will get updates suggested at the same time. I don't know of any way to change this using default means (apart from creating different deployments for each customer).

The problem with modifying the manifests and paths is that for security reasons the XML files that make up the deployment are signed, so you can not change them after creating the deployment without breaking their signature and thus breaking the ClickOnce installation/update process.

You could however, try to script the ClickOnce deployment process. [I found this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx) (I didn't read all of it, however) that describes how build a ClickOnce deployment outside Visual Studio. Maybe that would help you deploy for each customer, esp. since there is a section about InstallURL, SupportUrl, PublishURL and UpdateURL?

Comment: Thanks Thorsten
I've been looking into the same link myself, but was unsure it was the right way to go due to lack of knowledge about clickonce.
I’ll dive into it deeper now and hopefully solve my problem.
Thanks again
/Morten